# ViewFlipper not scrolling when scrolling vertically Android?

Tags: android, listview, viewflipper

I have LinearLayout with vertical orientation. It has two childs one ViewFlipper and Other ListView. ListView may have any number of items. When UI renders and i try to scroll vertically on screen ViewFlipper remains intact and ListView noves in its available place. I want ViewFlipper also to scroll UP rather than remaining intact.

Here is my XML Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/menuflipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="3000"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/nature3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/nature2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/nature3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/nature2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/nature3" />
    </ViewFlipper>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categorylist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You want to flip the ViewFlipper when it is swiped up.. right??